# Weird behavior when transforming objects using 4x4 Transformation Matrix

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, matrix, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to convert from 1 coordinate space to another. I have two set of objects representing points in space. Also, I have 6 objects in total and i am finding transformation Matrix between them and applying this transformation to 7th object using this piece of code:

```
      TestObject.transform.position = TransformationMatrix.MultiplyPoint(InitPosition);
      TestObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(TransformationMatrix.GetColumn(1),
                                        TransformationMatrix.GetColumn(2))* InitQT;
      Debug.Log("Test object is at" + TestObject.transform.position+"
      local position"+TestObject.transform.localPosition+" Calculation is "
      + TransformationMatrix.MultiplyPoint(InitPosition));
```

This code works however i translate or rotate second group of object (points) but what i realized is in inspector my test object has a different coordinate. I see in console

```
Test object is at(12.5, 2.5, 0.0) local position(12.5, 2.5, 0.0) Calculation is (12.5, 2.5, 0.0)
```

However in inspector i get the result `(12.5,2.5,-4.47034)`. I pause the game set z to zero it does not move but when i resume it becomes `-4.47034`.

I am using this scene to Test my Transformation. Normally i have to apply this transformation to Laser scanner to Unity coordinate system and even though this does not affect anything and objects are at the correct position, i am afraid this might be causing problems when i wanted to apply this transformation in Unity and laser scanner coordinate system transformation. Because that is not working like it works in test scene. Could it be the case that i am making a mistake using `MultiplyPoint`? Here is my inspector view: I am transforming from blue coordinate space to red. Thanks in advance for any help!

[image]

Comment: have you tried a simpler approach instead of transformation matrix? like `TestObject.transform.position += Vector3.one`

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that. I do not understand how adding `Vector3.one` would solve the problem. Because i have 3 points in each two different coordinate systems and i am finding the transformation matrix between them to apply it to a 4th point like it is done [here](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671) using [Accord.NET](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/wiki/Unity)

Comment: It won't solve the problem. It will help us identify this weird behaviour. I'm 99% percent sure that this does not have anything to do with matrix. but to confirm my guess I need you to check this.

Comment: Well adding `Vector3.one` works normal. If you would like to check the whole script i have it [here](https://github.com/alikanat001/RigidTransform)